# Tab key randomly stops working, why?

Tags: keyboard

At times, the <kbd>Tab</kbd> randomly stops working. 
Once I restart the computer it's working again.

Has anyone seen something like this before?

I'm using a TypeMatrix keyboard.

Intel(R) Core 2 Duo CPU 
E8400 @ 3.00Ghz
3.62 GB Ram
Dell Optiplex 780

Comment: What happens if you plug in another keyboard or use the onscreen keyboard?

Comment: Didn't know there was an onscreen keyboard. I like that. That's useful for testing things. Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Some other causes of this issue have been [identified](http://helpdeskgeek.com/help-desk/tab-key-not-working-in-windows-7/):

- KVM Switches
- Synergy (keyboard and mouse sharing with multiple computers over the network)
- Windows thinks some key is stuck: try pressing Ctrl and Alt
- StickyKeys is enabled: try pressing the Windows Key twice to turn it off
- Xerox Printer Drivers (Xerox Job Tracker, Xerox PrintingScout)
- Logmein, TeamViewer, [Citrix XenDesktop](http://forums.citrix.com/message.jspa?messageID=1650699)

Comment: Team viewer was opened on my system, I closed it, it is working now.

Comment: Lifesaver thanks you saved me from wasting a lot of time. :)

Comment: Another vote for Teamviewer! I have a Windows Surface with attached keyboard, plus a wireless keyboard. [Tab] wasn't working on either of them. Shut down Teamviewer, instantly [Tab] started working again!

Comment: @paul Thanks, TeamViewer was the case! That's weired, that had never happened before.

Comment: I just encountered this with a TeamViewer 12 session open in the background. Looks like TeamViewer was intercepting the Tab keypress and sending it to the remote session instead.

Comment: Never would have found it without your post.  TeamViewer open.  Who knew?

Answer (score 5):

In my case, it was that inside TeamViewer (remote system running Windows 10), I had opened the Start menu (you know, by clicking on the little window icon in the bottom left corner).  As long as that was up, Tab was not working on my local system!

I didn't have to reboot or disconnect my Teamviewer session, only to minimize the Start menu on the remote system.  Then Tab worked again!